# Cluster selection and formula in (longitudinal) GEE models

Tags: r, generalized-estimating-equations

I have a question according the "formula interface" from GEE models, for instance when using the `gee` function from the [R gee package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gee).

Let's say I have a measured quality of life (**QoL**), **education** and **sex** from 100 subjects at three different time points (**time**). If I understand the GEE model approach correctly, GEE can be used for longitudinal, clustered data. However, I wonder what my clusters would be? The cluster variable is passed to the argument `id` within the `gee` function, so what would be the right syntax if I want to measure change in **QoL** over **time**, and how this change differs depending on **education** and **sex**?

1. Is **time** my cluster variable?

`gee(QoL ~ education + sex, id = time)`

2. Is the subject-ID my cluster?

`gee(QoL ~ education + sex + time, id = subject-ID)`

However, this looks like a random slope approach of mixed models to me.

3. Is probably **education** my cluster?

`gee(QoL ~ sex + time, id = education)`

4. Last: I don't have any real clusters. But what would I then choose to analyze the longitudinal data, to account for the correlation of my DV **QoL** for same subjects at different time points?

Maybe I'm confused because I try to compare the formula syntax to the one from longitudinal data analysis with `lme4`, where the decision which variables to choose for random intercept and slope is quite clear (time and subject) - however, if I do not have individual differences (i.e. I'm interested in the population average), what are the clusters in GEE model for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use subject (or subject ID) as your cluster.  GEE takes into account the repeated measurements on clusters, in this case the repeated measure is on individuals over time.  So, you'd want to use

```
gee(QoL ~ education + sex + time, id = subject-ID)
```

An easy way to determine what the cluster is, is to determine what object are multiple measurements being taken on.  In this case, the multiple measurements are being made on a subject.  You aren't making measurements on "a time" or on "an education."

By the way, I would recommend using geeglm as you can control the ordering of the measurements using the `waves` argument to geeglm, which I find is usually needed.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I have looked at the `geeglm` package, seems to be similar to the `gee` package according formula syntax. I will give it a try.

Comment: No problem.  In my experience geeglm is easier to use and it takes a better accounting of ordered observations.

Comment: Just a short question for clarification: What is the difference in application of the `nlme::gls` function? When do I use `gls`? It can also deal with auto correlated residuals in longitudinal data, right?

Comment: Another question: would I use argument `waves = time` and not use **time** as predictor in my formula?

Comment: You would want time in the model statement.  Use waves to indicate the ordering of the measurements according to cluster and time within cluster.

Comment: Also, this might be of help to you:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geepack/vignettes/geepack-manual.pdf